# Why was Hermes allowed to say "Star Trek" when it is a banned phrase?

Tags: futurama

How come in the episode "Brannigan, Begin Again," Hermes says, "Star Trek," after the professor fails to compare their government to the United Nations to Fry? In a later episode of Futurama it is shown that you are not allowed to say the phrase "Star Trek."

Comment: To clarify: Farnsworth compares DOOP to the UN, which Fry hadn't heard of, so Hermes compared it to the Federation from Star Trek, which Fry understood.

Comment: I've seen an explanation which said (I'm paraphrasing) "they aren't actually saying *Star Trek*, but *Start Wreck*, a completely unrelated TV series that happened to be similar". I'll try to google for it - if I could find it I'll mention it as an answer. (Out of the existing ones, my favorite is Blue's answer.)

Answer (score 5):

Well, lots of things are illegal/banned, but people still do them anyways, especially in private. Hermes is prone to doing a few other illegal things as well. The episode where his son Dwight finds his 'cigar' comes to mind. "That's not a cigar! ... and it's not mine!"

Comment: Well, that sounds logical but when Fry says it in the Star Trek episode, Leela and bender take it very seriously!

Answer (score 4):

The episode was written before the Star Trek episode.  That is all I can provide.  (I've noticed this as well)

Comment: can you elaborate on this any more? Perhaps provide a source? Including little things like episode titles goes a long way when trying to improve answers. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is what I found

"Hermes mentions the Star Trek program. However, Star Trek has been banned (4ACV11), so he shouldn't have done it. But this continuity error appears in many other episodes.

Hermes has shown numerous times that he does not care about breaking the law and, since Planet Express is privately owned, the Police wouldn't know to interfere unless someone at the company told them to."

[Source:](http://theinfosphere.org/Brannigan,_Begin_Again)Under Goofs

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the alternate universes that allows him to say it.  This would also explain the 3 original crew backgrounds. Death by space wasps, space bees, and lost in space. We know that 3 universes exist.  The original, shot Hitler, and shot Eleanor Roosevelt. This is assumed to keep a timeline.

Comment: Can you provide a source? This seems like the most logical answer, if backed up in canon.

Comment: It would have to be assumed as just saying Star Trek will automatically call the police.